# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'view'

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to understand why I am receiving this error: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'view'`

The following piece runs fine. However if i uncomment the line that does the date type conversion then it fails with the error mentioned above.

Maybe its trivial but i dont know if im missing something or this is how pandas should behave. Any help would be appreciated

```
In [1]:

df = pd.DataFrame([['01-Nov-2015', 1, 0],['02-Nov-2015', 2, 3],['03-Nov-2015', 4, 5]], columns=('Date','c1','c2'))
#df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df
Out[1]:
    Date        c1  c2
0   01-Nov-2015 1   0
1   02-Nov-2015 2   3
2   03-Nov-2015 4   5

In [2]:

df!=0
Out[2]:
    Date    c1      c2
0   True    True    False
1   True    True    True
2   True    True    True
```

Comment: I don't get this error with Python 2.7, Pandas 0.17.

Comment: What version pandas are you using, this works fine on pandas `0.17.0`, python 3.4, numpy 1.9.2

Comment: I am using pandas `'0.15.2'` and numpy 1.9.2, python 2.7. I will upgrade my pandas and try again. Thanks for the hint

Comment: Yes, i upgraded to the latest pandas `0.17.0` and now it works fine. Maybe a bug in `v0.15` which i was using... Many thanks for the help guys!